Definition of Creation Operator via One-Particle State
In Weinberg's QFT V1 section 4.2, he defines the creation operator via one-particle state,
$$\Phi_{\mathbf{p}_1,\sigma_1,n_1} = a^{\dagger}(\mathbf{p}_1\sigma_1n_1)\Phi_{0}\tag{1}$$
where $\Phi_{0}$ is vacuum state.
Meanwhile, in the earlier chapter on the book, that is, section 2.5, he states that a specific bound state of two or more particles can be considered as one-particle state too. As far as I'm concerned, this means that one-particle state can represent composite particle that is not an elementary particle whose corresponding field does appear in Lagrangian of the theory. This idea, I think, is conformed in the latter chapter of the book, in section 10.2.
However, I wonder, for such one-particle state of composite particle, can we define creation operator like (1), if can, then could we write down the mode expansion in momentum-space and therefore there would be a field variable corresponding to the composite particle that appears in Lagrangian?
Which further make the composite particles no difference with the elementary particles?

Weinberg made it clear that bound states are still not satisfactorily defined in QFT. It is still an open problem.

Also, how's 凱米? There are so many fallen branches on the road...

@naturallyInconsistent I see. BTW the wind and rain are a bit heavy, but my family and I are safe. Thank you for your concern and reply.
